# Prove $1^3+2^3+\ldots +n^3= \left( \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right)^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Ok, so I have

$$P(n) = 1^3+2^3+3^3 + n^3= \left( \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right)^2 $$

assuming $n = k $

$P(k) = 1^3+2^3+3^3+ \cdots + k^3= (k(k+1)/2)^2$  < inductive hypothesis

$P(k) = 1^3+2^3+3^3+ \cdots + k^3 = (k(k+1)/2)^2$ < use as definition for $1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots +k^3$

inductive step, $n=k+1$

$$
\begin{align}
\ P(k+1) &= 1^3+2^3+3^3+ \cdots + k^3+(k+1)^3 \\
\ &= ((k+1)((k+1)+1)/2)^2 \\
\ &= (k(k+1)/2)^2 + (k+1)^3 \\
\ &= ((k+1)((k+1)+1)/2)^2 \\
\ &= (k^2(k+1)^2/4+(4(k+1)^3)/4 \\
\ &=((k+1)^2(k+2)^2)/4 \\
\end{align}
$$

I then get rid of the 4's keep expanding this out, and continuously get equations that aren't equal. What am I doing wrong here? I've been at this question for an hour and I still have a shitload to go, please god don't give me a vague hint that I'll have to guess at for another hour. Excuse my annoyance lol.

Comment: "Therefore..." How does the next statement follow from the prvious one? You've just written out $P(k+1)$ which doesn't follow directly from the previous steps.

Comment: not sure what that means, I edited it. Not exactly what I was looking for but thanks anyway?

Answer (score 1):

When you prove something via induction, you have to set up a base case and an induction hypothesis.  Before that, though, you have to write out your statement. Note how mine differs from yours:

$$1^3 + 2^3 + \ldots + n^3 = \left( \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right)^2$$

Namely, there's an ellipsis in there. That means something different from what yours says.

Now, for the base case, you establish that the statement is true for some specific value of $n$.  Here, we can use $1$:  It's easy to prove, which is always nice.  So:

> Base case:
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{i=1}^1 i^3 &= 1 \\
> \ &= \frac{1(2)}{2} \\
> \end{align}
> $$
>   And so the statement holds for $n = 1$.

Note that we cannot prove anything right off the bat for $n = k$; $k$ is just another unknown.

Next, we set up the induction hypothesis:

> Assume the identity holds for $n = k$. Now we show that it also holds for $n = k + 1$.

You can do this because you've already shown that it holds for at least *one* value of $k$ — that is, $k = 1$.

From here, you take advantage of the fact that

> $$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i^3 = \sum_{i=1}^{k} i^3 + \sum_{i=k+1}^{k+1} i^3$$

— from which point, it shouldn't be too much work.